# MYSQL remove <font> tags and style="" attributes

Tags: mysql, strip-tags, inline-styles

I'm redesigning a web site that has a bunch of tags in the content pasted in from Word. I would like to get rid of every instance of a font tag.

I would also like to get rid of all the inline style usually put in with

```
<span style="font-family:Verdana, etc.;">...</span>
```

I want to keep all the a, em, br, strong tags, so I don't want to strip all tags just the ones that effect the stylings of the content.

This content is all in a MySQL database and a MySQL solution is preferred over a PHP solution, but I will take either at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best solution to the problem but here is what I'm doing. I tried some different scripts to get the info from the database, clean it up and post it back with PHP, but nothing really worked that well. Everything I used messed up the data, more than it helped. GIGO.

I decided on using javascript (jQuery) to take all the attributes out of <font> tags and clear the style attribute of all <span> and <p> tags. Everything looks fine after doing this. All future content will be right going into the system, but all the old content has the ugly code still in the database, which is cleaned up enough to display right on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse HTML with RegExp and MySQL is for storing&retrieving data, not filtering it.

Just use http://htmlpurifier.org/ to clean your HTML in PHP.

Comment: Would this solution leave the database alone, just to do the filtering on after retrieving the content from the MySQL? I would prefer to clean up the database once, instead filtering what it gives every time the PHP runs.

Comment: You can't full parse HTML true - but you can probably recognize enough patterns with regexes to make an SQL approach workable as a one-off cliean up

Comment: See also this question for approaches for doing regex based replacements in MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: @Johann Dyck you can do filtering before inserting data to data base or just make script to clean up everything in database pernamently (retrieve data -> clean up -> update it back)